# Talend filter rows for newest date

Tags: filtering, talend, unix-timestamp

I have a table with n entries for each id. I also have a timestamp. I need to keep only the row with the latest timestamp for each id. I sort by id than by desc(timestamp). But what to do next? tMemorizeRows? You need to specify how many rows to memorize. But n is not constant. And can I somehow use FilterRow?
Many thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0):

After sorting the data by ID asc and Timestamp desc, you can use tAggregateRow and choose ID as group by column. Use "first" for all the remaining columns. This will give you the first value of each column for respective ID, as you have already sorted by ID asc and Timestamp desc.